# Reading a String from Binary File returns nothing

Tags: java, string, binary, binaryfiles

I try to program a simple game (but my question is not so game specific) so i wrote a little `MapLoader`. At the moment it only reads the File Header and prints it on the Screen.

Info:

- `Signature` is a `byte`
- `Version` is an `int`
- `length` is a `long`
- `name` is a 32 byte long `String`

Also, all these are signed as there is no unsigned in Java.

However i have a function `toString(byte[] array)`. Its implemented like this:

```
private String toString(byte[] array) {
    char[] buffer = new char[array.length];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(array.length);

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (char) array[i];
        builder.append(buffer[i]);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I pass in an sub-array of `data[]` (holding all data)

```
header.name = toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 11, 32));
```

But when doing

```
Debugger.debug("Signatur: " +  header.signature);
Debugger.debug("Version: " + header.version);
Debugger.debug("Länge: " + header.length);
Debugger.debug("Name: " + header.name);
```

I only get:

```
Signatur: 86
Version: 1
Länge: 14
Name:
```

My Map File looks like this:

```
56 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0E 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 0A
```

Comment: What is `Debugger`? If it's your own class, please show us the `debug` method.

Comment: Debugger just is a wraparround for System.out.println(). It just adds an boolean storing if debugging is enabled or not.

Comment: Does it work if you use the correct index with `Arrays.copyOfRange` ("byte+int+long = "`1+4+8 =13 != 11`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `java.lang.String` constructors that takes a byte array as a parameter, rather than rolling your own. The `String` implementation deals properly with all the character set issues.

Comment: I tried header.name = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 11, 32)); and it didnt work, gave the same output